# How to parse a text by line and store some values in an array

Tags: ruby

I want to parse the following text and find lines that start with `'+'` or `'-'`:

```
--- a/product.json
+++ b/product.json
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 {
-  "name": "Coca Cola",
-  "barcode": "41324134132"
+  "name": "Sprite",
+  "barcode": "41324134131"
 }
\ No newline at end of file
```

When I find a such line, I want to store the attribute name. I.e., for:

```
-  "name": "Coca Cola",
```

I want to store `name` in `minus_array`.

Comment: It looks like you are parsing `diff` results. You might try the [unified_diff gem](https://github.com/rkneufeld/unified_diff). Disclaimer: I have never used that gem.

Comment: What is the attribute name for lines like `--- a/product.json`?

Comment: When you ask for code you need to show what you've tried and explain why it's not working for you. See the [help/on-topic], especially #3, for more information on how to ask a question correctly.

Comment: @sawa, lines starting with `---` and `+++` are the original and new files being compared. The lines starting with `- ` and `+ ` inside the curl-braces, (`-` or `+` followed by whitespace) are the significant ones.

Comment: @zwippie the unified_diff gem doesn't work with this. At least I didn't know how to use the UnifiedDiff.parse function.

Comment: @sawa that line has to be skipped!

Comment: @enter08 You didn't write that in the question.

Comment: @sawa yes, my bad, I thought it was implied. This is a Compare result of the Diff function from GitLab. I want to analyse the output to mark the added, removed and changed attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate over the lines, and find lines that begin with either `-` or `+` followed by whitespace:

```
text = %[
--- a/product.json
+++ b/product.json
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 {
-  "name": "Coca Cola",
-  "barcode": "41324134132"
+  "name": "Sprite",
+  "barcode": "41324134131"
 }
\ No newline at end of file
]

text.lines.select{ |l| l.lstrip[/^[+-]\s/] }.map{ |s| s.split[1] }
# => ["\"name\":", "\"barcode\":", "\"name\":", "\"barcode\":"]
```

- `lines` splits a string on line-ends, returning the entire line, including the trailing line-end character.
- `lstrip` removes whitespace at the start of the line. This is to normalize lines allowing the regex pattern to be a bit more simple.
- `l.lstrip[/^[+-]\s/]` is a bit of Ruby String slight-of-hand, that basically says to apply the pattern to the string and return the matching text. If nothing matches in the string `nil` will be returned, which acts as false as far as `select` is concerned. If the string has something that matches the pattern, `[]` will return the text, which acts as a true value for `select`, which then passes on that string.
- `map` iterates over all elements that `select` passes to it, and transforms the element by splitting it on spaces, which is the default behavior of `split`. `[1]` returns the *second* element in the string.

Here's an alternate path to the same place:

```
ary = []
text.lines.each do |l|
  i = l.strip
  ary << i if i[/^\{$/] .. i[/^}$/]
end
ary[1..-2].map{ |s| s.split[1] } # => ["\"name\":", "\"barcode\":", "\"name\":", "\"barcode\":"]
```

That'll get you started. How to remove duplicates, strip the leading/trailing double-quotes and colon is your task.

Comment: This works. I'm using this to make two arrays. One with attributes that had - in front, and another with '+' 's. So, there won't be duplicates. With that, I can't now find the intersection, union and difference to mark the added, removed and changed lines in a file. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
text.split(/\n/).select { |l| l =~ /^\+./ }
```

If you're using file:

```
File.open('your_file.txt', "r").select { |l| l =~ /^\+./ }
```

Comment: This is part one of my problem. This is the output: `["+++ b/product.json", "@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@", "+  \"name\": \"Sinalco\",", "+  \"barcode\": \"41324134131\""]` The first line is expected. I'll skip it somehow. The second line in the output is not ok. Fixed with: `.select { |l| l =~ /^\+./ }` I think I'll manage the rest. Thnx

Comment: @enter08 If you assume that after `+` there is a space, you can use this: `text.split(/\n/).select { |l| l =~ /^\+\s./ }`

Comment: @DarekNędza yes! The output's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.readlines("file.txt").each do |line|
    if line.starts_with? '+ ' || line.starts_with? '- '
        words = line.split(":")
        key = words[0].match(/".*"/)
        val = words[1].match(/".*"/)
        # You can then do what you will with the name and value here
        # For example, minus_array << if line.starts_with? '-'
    end
end
```

I'm not entirely sure of the constraints you have with this, so I can't give a more specific answer. Basically, you can iterate the lines of a file with `File.readlines('file') { }`. Then we check for a the string to start with `+` or `-`, and grab the name and value accordingly. I put a space in the `starts_with?` because if I didn't it would also match the top two lines of your example.

Hopefully that's what you were looking for!

Comment: Looks very good. Just, how to make this work for strings (text). I tried `@diffs[0].diff.lines.each do |line| ... end`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group according to the first character:

```
groups = text.lines.group_by { |l| l[0] }

groups['-']
# => ["--- a/product.json\n", "-  \"name\": \"Coca Cola\",\n", "-  \"barcode\": \"41324134132\"\n"]
groups['+']
# => ["+++ b/product.json\n", "+  \"name\": \"Sprite\",\n", "+  \"barcode\": \"41324134131\"\n"]
```